# How to create custom metrics in prometheus?

Tags: python, prometheus, metrics

I'm setting up a monitoring PoC for future requirements. The PoC is developed locally on my computer. To monitor metric i use Prometheus and Grafana.
I want to count the number of files received and the time spend to process it. For that i need to create custom metrics.

I'm using python 2.7.5. For now i have linked Prometheus and the target. I receive metrics but don't know how to create metrics that i want.

```py
counter = prom.Counter('python_my_counter', 'This is my counter')
gauge = prom.Gauge('python_my_gauge', 'This is my gauge')
histogram = prom.Histogram('python_my_histogram', 'This is my histogram')
summary = prom.Summary('python_my_summary', 'This is my summary')


def thr():
    while True:
        counter.inc(random.random())
        gauge.set(random.random() * 15 - 5)
        histogram.observe(random.random() * 10)
        summary.observe(random.random() * 10)
        process_request(random.random() * 5)

        time.sleep(1)
```

I expect the sum of files received "count the number of files received" metric.
The time spent processing a file (i.e 2s) and the sum of time spent processing a file (50s).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you don't need all these metrics for your use case. Just register `summary` metric with prometheus, something like:

```
from prometheus_client import Summary
import time
# Create a metric to track time spent and requests made.
REQUEST_TIME = Summary('request_processing_seconds', 'Time spent processing request')
# Decorate function with metric.
@REQUEST_TIME.time()
def process_request(t):
    """A dummy function that takes some time."""
    time.sleep(t)
```

Then you have `request_processing_seconds_count` and `request_processing_seconds_sum` metrics available.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How can i generate a metric that return constant value over time (i.e metric = 1) ?

Comment: what use case you are trying to solve by returning constant value over time?
If you want just a constant value, you can register any `counter` metric and never increment it.
AFAIK metrics are not made for that. Please read about when (not) to use metrics here: https://medium.com/@copyconstruct/logs-and-metrics-6d34d3026e38

Comment: @kalimba How to register custom metric with Prometheus?